# Selecting "Improve Edit" and editing nothing sometimes allows the review to be submitted

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, suggested-edits

Just now I was viewing a question, and saw that there was a suggested edit. I opened the dialog box to review the edit, and saw that the only improvement they were making was adding indentation so that the code would display properly. Sure that there was something else that could be improved, I selected <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd>. However, I couldn't find any additional edits worth making, so I left it alone and selected <kbd>Save Edits</kbd>.

Here's the gif for the additional proof:

[image]

And the outcome in the revisions:

> [image]

The edit was immediately applied! (Due to having that privilege from 2000 rep)

The edit was still attributed to the person who suggested the edit, and when I viewed the approval description, it said:

[image]

My name doesn't appear anywhere in the review history. It can only be seen that this happened by clicking on the "edit approved" link in the review history.

I feel that my action should instead have been considered "Approve", because I made no edits. Curiously, it labelled it as approved by the "Community" as well, which I know is also used for when the OP approves an edit, but I know this wasn't the OP because it was approved 1 second after I clicked save, and also because I can reproduce the behavior.

Is this the intended behavior? I understand that selecting "Improve Edit" but not actually making any edits is deceitful, and I should have been more careful, but it seems very unusual that I could trump the "3 person must approve" rule just by clicking "Improve Edit" and then not making edits.

---

Worth to mention that it doesn't happen all the time. Sometimes you're properly presented with this message:

> [image]

It doesn't look like the behavior is predictable, sometimes it appears completely random (you can't know for sure if the review will be successful or not).

Comment: The reason Community is attributed to approving it is that it carries a diamond which means it has a binding vote which immediately approves the edit...

Comment: @JonClements But should I be able to control what the Community account does by selecting "Improve Edit" but not making any changes to the edit?

Comment: I think it's by design because sometimes suggested edits can get "stuck" waiting to be approved/declined which prevents anyone else suggesting an edit or making an edit to the post. Since you're a 2k+ user and could technically make an edit yourself (but can't because the suggested edit is still pending) then you might want to do what you've done to force through a decent edit which'll then open up the post for further (suggested) edits.

Comment: @JonClements So I should prefer to select "Improve Edit" instead of selecting "Approve" since it gets the post moving along quicker? I just feel that if this was intended, then my approval vote should also instantly put the edit in effect instead of still making it wait for 2 other people to review.

Comment: Nope - you're trusted to use it responsibly. It's best to follow the normal workflow and hit approve and move onto the next review unless it's a good enough suggested edit but you've spotted a couple of other bits it could do with. Or, *very sparingly* use it to push through stuck reviews...

Comment: @JonClements Interesting. I didn't know this was actually a tactic used by reviewers. Thanks for the info! On the [description for the 2k privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), it didn't mention any guidelines for when to use Improve Edit.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252623/i-improved-an-edit-but-did-i-actually

Comment: @NathanTuggy So it *is* a bug? This is a little confusing.

Comment: @4castle: I would say so; Improve should only allow short-circuiting approval if there's an actual edit to be made.

Comment: @m0sa That's wrong. The edit could still go through in the suggested edits review queue, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12923697). And [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/364119).

Comment: @nicael you should get [this] (if you don't change anything) in the queue

Comment: @m0sa http://i.stack.imgur.com/VT10U.gif

Comment: I seem to recall that Improving Edits leaves two revisions in the revision history; one for the suggested edit and one for the person who improved it.

Comment: @TylerH It doesn't do that when no edits are made though. It just leaves 1 revision, and it's attributed to the person who suggested it.

Comment: @m0sa As for the message you've mentioned: it may appear in *both* situations, but it also may *not* appear, and let the edit go through. You can seemingly never predict whether it will appear or not.

Answer (score 15):

I've managed to reproduce this reliably:

- The suggested edit must be on a question
- The suggested edit must *not* modify the question's tags

Such edits can be approved via "Improve Edits" without actually making changes.

The root cause appears to be an issue with how tags are encoded internal to the check that's supposed to catch this.

This is fixed as of January 18th, 2019

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to to improve a suggested edit, and then submit it without making any changes, and I got the following error message:

[image]

So it seems it's been implemented already. Which means yes, the system is designed to catch attempts to force a suggested edit through, and it just isn't working properly. You should probably adjust your question/bug report to reflect that.

Comment: @nicael So really the question needs to be rephrased to "why don't I always get the error message". You also shouldn't have edited that into the quesiton *after* I had posted this answer because it invalidates the answer.

Comment: Probably, you're right :)

Comment: When reviewing the edit from the question itself though, it **never** has the error. When I posted the bug originally, I never made any claims about the review queue's behavior.

Comment: @4castle See my comment above.

Comment: And sorry, I haven't noticed you were posting the answer, I didn't intend to break your answer. But it's not correct anyway.

Comment: @nicael Well, it is correct; the error message is implemented and it prevented me from submitting a no-change improvement to a suggested edit. I'm unable to reproduce OP's issue. So there *is* a catch in the system designed to prevent this. If anything, the *question* is based on a mistaken premise (which you've already agreed to)

Comment: @Tyler [Please see this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252623/i-improved-an-edit-but-did-i-actually). Yes, it is implemented, but doesn't function properly anytime.

Comment: I tried again just now and it didn't show the error.

Comment: @4castle And considering this answer and ensuing discussion, I recommend you heavily edit your question to just be a simple bug reporting the fact that it doesn't always catch a lack of improvement, rather than asking if that's OK. Since we've determined that the system *should* (and sometimes does) stop you from this behavior, that obviates the need to answer the question in your post title.

Comment: @nicael I've adjusted my answer to also address the updated question

Comment: @nicael My original bug report was never about the review queue. It was about the review dialog when viewed from the question (which **always** has the bug)

Comment: @4castle Nonono :) [Example gif](http://i.stack.imgur.com/P4Hts.gif), and there is [the edit to reproduce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38226886/how-to-handle-events-in-crdxe-through-javascript-in-aem).

Comment: @4castle Your gif does not indicate that, and it doesn't always reproduce it there for me. I get the same error there.

Comment: @Tyler It was my gif. And 4castle isn't really right either.

Comment: When the bug is fixed, a mod will mark it [status-completed]. I'm still able to reproduce the bug. It seems to be intermittent now.

Comment: @4castle It has been intermittent all the time, not just now :)

Comment: In case you're curious, [>this edit<](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12924849) was my instance of where it's still happening. (I did it 2 minutes after you posted your answer)