# Is it sometimes OK when reviewing suggested edits to just improve an edit without any changes?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

This might have been asked before, but I couldn't find anything.

Sometimes there are suggested edits that are clearly good. But if I hit Approve, it's just going to sit around and wait for two other people to approve before it finally gets updated. I'm wondering if it's OK to sort of "cut the red tape" and just hit Improve Edit and change nothing so that it gets updated quicker. Let me break my question into some specific cases:

1. An edit that removes confidential information that the OP probably doesn't want shared. I'm pretty sure that the answer to this is "yes". We want to hide that info as soon as possible.
2. An edit that removes profanity and very vulgar language.
3. A little less severe, but how about a edit that removes a "SOLVED" that was added by the OP to the question title.

Comment: In the three cases you cite, there is no reason to bother abusing the system to guarantee an edit is approved, because it is going to get approved anyway, even by robo-reviewers. "Speed" doesn't matter; edits get reviewed *very* quickly. Aside from that, [it appears that what you describe may not even be possible](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327397/selecting-improve-edit-and-editing-nothing-sometimes-allows-the-review-to-be-s).

Comment: @CodyGray Oh ok I didn't realize that it's not even possible. I contemplated doing it just recently and wanted to get the community's opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not appropriate to abuse the ability to improve an edit to unilaterally vote on an edit without actually improving on the edit.  If you want to improve on the edit, *actually* improve on the edit.

Comment: But what about my case #1? If there is nothing else to improve and there is confidential information. Wouldn't we want to remove that ASAP?

Comment: @KodosJohnson It's still there, even if you edit it out (in the revision history).  And either way, the source is compromised.  Whether it's shown for 5 minutes or 6, it's still a compromised credential that needs to be revoked immediately by the authenticator.

Comment: @KodosJohnson Very marginally so, and only a very short period of time sooner.  Either way it's still very much too late.

Comment: @Kodos There is a specific procedure for [redacting confidential information](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317454/4639281) from posts.