# It requires two approve edits to approve the edit, but improve edit and changing nothing, edits the post instantly

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits

I think the question is pretty obvious.

When there is an edit request in the post and I click on approve edit, it says it still requires an extra approval to apply the changes.

But when I click on *Improve Edit* and save changes without making any changes, the changes are applied immediately in the name of the person who suggested the edit.

Is this a bug or something else?

**EDIT for possible duplicate:**
I understand that it is good that an edit approval requires two votes. But it is possible to approve it single-handedly by clicking the improve edit and saving it without making any changes. So is this a bug or a feature?

**EDIT for another possible duplicate:**
Why should I bother waiting another approval when I can approve it instantly?

Comment: @RobertLongson check edited question.

Comment: I closed as a different dupe than the one Robert proposed. As far as I understand, what you describe ("improve" but making no changes) should *not* be possible. That bug has been reported before, but not reproduced reliably by the developers.

Comment: @CodyGray But there is only an answer with -3 votes. Should I rely on it? Also why should I bother waiting another approval when I can approve it instantly?

Comment: Why do you feel you need to singlehandedly approve edits? In what way does that benefit you?

Comment: The reason why you should bother is because what you're doing is an abuse of the system. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341437/is-it-sometimes-ok-when-reviewing-suggested-edits-to-just-improve-an-edit-withou

Comment: @RobertLongson I am just reporting the bug. Also instantly approving edit will allow me to view the code in proper format before answering the question.

Comment: @CodyGray if it is abuse of the system, why is it allowed to do? If you say it is required in some cases, why is it not allowed to do directly?

Comment: That's the definition of abuse: doing something that you should not be doing, but you've found a way to do anyway.

Comment: @CodyGray so this is kind of a "hack". Are the developers aware of it? If they are, then why aren't they fixing it?

Comment: The system doesn't prevent you from posting complete nonsense or approving vandalism of posts but those are still abuse, there are lots of bad things you can do but shouldn't.

Comment: They aren't fixing it because most people are sensible enough not to engage in things they can but shouldn't do. Those few that do are warned and/or suspended.

Comment: This is exhausting. I already told you and provided a link confirming that it has been reported before, but hasn't been able to be reliably reproduced. A bug cannot be fixed unless it can be reproduced. That doesn't change that exploiting it is an abuse of the system. I don't know what point you're trying to prove here.

Comment: @CodyGray Alright thanks for your time and letting me know about this rule.