# What is difference between Approve Edit & Improve Edit?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I've approved edit for this question: ([No suitable records were found verify your bundle identifier is correct Xcode 9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50533884/no-suitable-records-were-found-verify-your-bundle-identifier-is-correct-xcode-9))

but still it needs 1 more approve vote.

> This suggestion still needs 1 approve vote from other reviewers.

Next moment, I improve edit for (https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19837063). Without making any change (improvement), I directly click on 'Save' button and edit was saved (approved).

I haven't made any change (improvement) in both questions but `Approve Edit` needs 1 more approve vote and `Improve Edit` doesn't. (Improve edit should not be accepted until user add its input. At least it should force me to make some (minimum characters/contents) changes.)

Why?

Comment: On meta duplicates don't have to have answers. This is a bug and simply hasn't been fixed yet. It doesn't need multiple reports to all be open about it really does it?

Answer (score 5):

Approve edit means that the reviewer simply set a positive approve vote to the suggested edit. Two approve edits are required for that suggested edit to take effect. The edit is officially credited to the user who made the edit suggestion.

Improve edit means that reviewer approved, and improved the edit. It is considered as positive outcome for the one who suggested the edit instantly. The suggested edit is taken into effect in an improved form immediately, as if the reviewer made an edit based on the edit suggestion. The edit suggestion is **Approved**, but the edit is officially credited to the reviewer of that post.

Improve edit is an **instant** suggested edit approval, equivalent to two approval votes. The reason is because the editor either is the author of the post being given the suggested edit, or that the editor have the edit privilege, and have priority over suggested edits.

Usage of Improve edit should not be used to exploit the two-approval loophole "This edit is critical or very good" (similarly Reject and Edit should not be used to simply state "this suggested edit is so poor it should be scrapped right away"). You probably accidentally declared "Improve" without improving anything. See [Selecting "Improve Edit" and editing nothing sometimes allows the review to be submitted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327397/selecting-improve-edit-and-editing-nothing-sometimes-allows-the-review-to-be-s) for more details about that possible loophole.

Comment: Logically your answer it right. But I didn't make any change in Improve edit. Improve edit should not be accepted until user add its input. At least it should ask me to make some (minimum character/contents) changes.

Comment: I understand. One is probably using "improve" as a loophole to say "This suggestion is very good" and uses the "improve" option to give an instant approval. In this case, he accidentally insta-approved the edit because he does not realize that all "improve" edits are instant approvals. Similarly, all "reject and edit" votes are instant edit rejections.