# Why does a second person need to approve an edit I could have made without any review at all?

Tags: discussion, edits

Sometimes, I want to clean up a question, just by adding code blocks or changing other trivial formatting. I have enough rep to make those edits without review.

The problem is, sometimes another user has already proposed such edits. This blocks me from making the edit myself. I could approve the edit, but that needs a second person to also approve the edit. Result: The question remains hard to read.

Why does a second person need to approve an edit I can make myself without review?

Comment: I've found [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327397/8681) which covers the same subject, except it's the wrong way around: Being able to insta-approve the edit is treated as a bug, not the way it's supposed to work.

Comment: There's always "Approve and edit" which automatically approved the pending edit...

Comment: @Cerbrus I don't need to make additional edits. Just approve the pending one.

Comment: Because people don't properly check the edits they're reviewing, and a second reviewer makes it more likely that the correct decision is reached.  It's an unfortunate situation.  Arguably, there's _maybe_ less chance of that outside of the review queue?

Comment: The privilege to access that review queue is also given at 2k rep. What's so bad about having 2 sets of eyes take a look at a pending edit?

Comment: @Cerbrus Well, arguably, the fact that that queue is constantly chock full is bad.

Comment: Well, sure, but I don't thing reducing the amount of votes it takes to 1 is a very good idea.

Comment: Use "Approve and edit", and make some other change. I find it hard to believe that you wouldn't be able to find anything else to edit/improve.

Comment: Okay, apparently I'll have to deal with this using a workaround. So be it.

Comment: Also related: [Reviewer overboard! Or a request to improve the onboarding guidance for new reviewers in the suggested edits queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420349/)

Answer (score 16):

Since you have sufficient reputation to edit without review, you can choose approve and edit or reject and edit. In either case you can proceed to make the edit you wish to and the prior suggested edit will be directly approved or rejected.

If you choose to simply approve or reject, you're right that you will end up temporarily blocked from further editing but unfortunately we have to have it this way because of the existence of robo-reviewers who simply trawl through the review queues and approve everything (till they get blocked).

Comment: "unfortunately we have to have it this way because of the existence of robo-reviewers" - I [still think the overall design is terrible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420357/523612). At an absolute bare minimum, the system should be able to distinguish between approve votes cast from the queue and those cast from directly viewing the question.